# Send Multiple attachment using sp_send_db_mail sql server

Tags: sql-server-2014, sp-send-dbmail

Can anyone advise if I can send multiple attachments using sp_send_db_mail in sql server 2014, I've 2 files and file names are dynamic so i'm picking the files with variables. Here's what I'm using:

@file_attachments = @filename;@filename1 which says incorrect syntax. However it works fine with one attachment .

Comment: You're missing single quotes around the attachements.

Comment: I've found a workaround for this, I took another variable and merged these 2 variables which worked. :)